# Calendar in lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

So I have a date field on my form...and I have have two other fields that change when the date changes. At first when I had one field and updated the date the field also updated. However, when i added the second field...it stopped working...are there like events or something that are calling the methods that set the fields/result and if so...how do I access them...or how can I do this so that both fields update when the date updates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the first date field selected in the entity designer (not screen), select the Write Code dropdown at the top of the screen edit window and select the _Changed event. Write whatever you want to do to otehr fields in the code that appears.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to handle this.

1. At the "entity" level (if you need to "store" the results of the calculation). Open the table in the table designer (as suggested in the previous reply), click the date property (that triggers the change), then "Write Code", then set the other properties' values in the Entity_Changed method. This would be the recommended method, if you wanted the same calculations to occur no matter how many screens are bound to the entity.
2. Also at the "entity" level (if you don't need to "store" the results, but only display them). You can create "computed" properties in the entity. LS is very clever & keeps track of the "dependencies" between properties for you. If you change the value of a property on which other computed properties are dependent, LS will update them for you automatically, without any extra code.
3. At the screen level. You can implement an INotifyPropertyChanged event handler for the property that the screen is bound to. When you change the actual value of date control, you can then manually set the values of the other dependent properties.

Hope this helps.